# Win + tab is not working anymore

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Win Tab used to tab thru my open windows. Some how I have shut it off. How do I turn it back on as well as how do I view transparent windows that are open

Comment: Is Aero enabled? I assume its Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable Windows Aero? I'm pretty sure that's an Aero-specific feature. (**Edit:** In fact, I'm positive it is because I just disabled Aero and Win + Tab stopped working.)

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-aero-on-windows-vista/

Answer (score 1):

It requires your video drivers to be working properly, Aero must be enabled, and dwm.exe must be running in task manager. If dwm.exe is not running it won't work. dwm.exe aka Desktop Window Manager is partially responsible for the rendering actual video feeds of each application window for flip3d to work.

Source: Experience with Vista and Win7